# What is the difference between dev c++ and online compiler?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

My code is working at dev c++ but it is not work at online compiler. What is the problem?

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[5][20], t[20], instr[5][20];
    int i, j;
    printf("5 Adet Kelime Giriniz : \n\n");

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
            printf("%d . ",i+1);
            scanf("%s", &str[i]);
            strcpy(instr[1], strrev(str[i]));
    }

    printf("%s",str[i]);

    for(i=1; i<5; i++)
    {
            for(j=1; j<5; j++)
            {
                    if(strcmp(str[j-1], str[j])>0)
                    {
                            strcpy(t, str[j-1]);
                            strcpy(str[j-1], str[j]);
                            strcpy(str[j], t);
                    }
            }
    }

    printf("\n Alfabetik Siralama : \n\n");
    int counter=1;
    for(i=4; i>-1; i--)
    {
            printf("%d . ",counter);
            printf("%s",str[i]);
            printf("\n");
            counter++;
    }
    return 0;
```

}

Here online compiler error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTW6r.png)

How can I solve this problem? İs it about code or compiler?

Answer (score 0):

all strings are char arrays, but not all char arrays are strings. 
the compiler doesn't allow you to do the assignment here

`scanf("%s", &str[i])`

When you pass arrays to functions in C, they decay to pointers to the first item.
so this is the same as`scanf("%s", &str[i][0])` and this is causing errors and undefined behaviors